# Overriding keyboard input in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

Is it possible to override/catch all keydown and keyup events during a minor mode?

I would like to do such a thing for several reasons, but mainly to try an alternative input method which I have not found any reasonable way of doing, in which key combinations would produce input, but in which it would be bothersome to re-press keys (it would be simpler to just hold them down if they are used in several combinations in a row).

Answer (score 0):

If your minor mode is at the top of the list of all active minor-modes, its keymap will be queried before all other modes are queried (unless some even higher precedence cases fall into place, cf. ["Searching Keymaps"](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Searching-Keymaps.html#Searching-Keymaps) in the Emacs Lisp documentation).

This means that you can at least handle all key events before other modes do, by binding them in your modes' keymap. You can also define a "catch all" key binding that matches every key event that is not otherwise bound in your map:

```lisp
(define-key my-minor-mode-map [t] 'my-catch-all-command)
```

However, this will not help you getting information about key releases. Perhaps you'll find it worthwhile checking out [Key chord mode](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/key-chord.el) for that.